# tsibble: Extract two keys from a ts object

Tags: tsibble

I'm working with the Seatbelts ts dataset and want to convert it to a tsibble where I can use `DriversKilled` grouped by `law`, or including `law` as a key to be used later.

Using

`head(as_tsibble(Seatbelts))`

creates the tsibble with the date index as expected, but only the first ts variable (DriversKilled) as the key.

Trying

`head(as_tsibble(Seatbelts, key=c(DriversKilled, law))`

gives me the same thing. How can I extract two keys from the Seatbelts ts object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Seatbelts` object is a multivariate `ts` object (`mts`).

```r
class(Seatbelts)
#> [1] "mts" "ts"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The `key` option does not exist in the `as_tsibble(<mts>)` method like it does for the `as_tsibble(<tibble>)` method. You can learn more about how to use `as_tsibble()` for `mts` objects with:

```r
?as_tsibble.mts
```

The most appropriate way to convert this data to a tsibble would be:

```r
library(tsibble)
as_tsibble(Seatbelts, pivot_longer = FALSE)
#> # A tsibble: 192 x 9 [1M]
#>       index DriversKilled drivers front  rear   kms PetrolPrice VanKilled   law
#>       <mth>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1969 Jan           107    1687   867   269  9059       0.103        12     0
#>  2 1969 Feb            97    1508   825   265  7685       0.102         6     0
#>  3 1969 Mar           102    1507   806   319  9963       0.102        12     0
#>  4 1969 Apr            87    1385   814   407 10955       0.101         8     0
#>  5 1969 May           119    1632   991   454 11823       0.101        10     0
#>  6 1969 Jun           106    1511   945   427 12391       0.101        13     0
#>  7 1969 Jul           110    1559  1004   522 13460       0.104        11     0
#>  8 1969 Aug           106    1630  1091   536 14055       0.104         6     0
#>  9 1969 Sep           107    1579   958   405 12106       0.104        10     0
#> 10 1969 Oct           134    1653   850   437 11372       0.103        16     0
#> # … with 182 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

A 'key' variable in a tsibble should uniquely identify a time series. For each key combination, there cannot be any time duplicates.

In this dataset, there are 8 different measured variables (things that vary over time) from a single time series. As such, this dataset should contain no key variables.

An example of a key variable for this data could be 'Country'. The `Seatbelts` dataset describes road casualties in Great Britain, however if it contained more than one country you could consider the data containing a time series for each country. This would warrant specifying 'Country' as a key variable. More details on setting up a tsibble can be found here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/tsibbles.html